# Is it possible to uninstall GitLab but leave the git server and the git repository intact?

Tags: git, gitlab

I am finding GitLab just too much of a resource hog on the VM I'm running it on and I'm unsure if I need to move the repository off to another machine before I remove it or if I can uninstall GitLab and the git server will still just work afterwards (which would obviously be a better/easier way forward)?
The VM is a Centos 7.2 build and the version of gitlab is ce-10.8.7-ce.0.el7.x86_64.

Comment: What git server are you talking about?

Comment: Sorry, just showing my general ignorance. I had thought that there was a git server and a git client. I realise this is a very basic misconception ... sorry.

Comment: Check out the [documentation on repository paths](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/repository_storage_paths.html) which should help you find the repositories. They should be bare repositories and you should be able to keep them. You probably won't be able to access them externally without some further setup.